# Pegar dados de outro site, através da ClassName

Tags: php

Como posso buscar dados presentes no HTML de outro site?

A parte do html do outro site é essa:

```
<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'>
  <span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman";color:black'>COTAÇÕES</span>
  <span style='mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"'><o:p></o:p></span>
</p>
```

No código do meu site tentei fazer assim:

```
 $html = new DOMDocument();
 $html->loadHTMLFile('http://www.agropan.coop.br/cotac.htm');

 echo $html->getElementByClassName('MsoNormal').getAttribute("p");
```

Na verdade, eu gostaria de buscar apenas o conteudo "COTAÇÕES" desde
 que ele seja buscado pela `ClassName`, como devo fazer?

Comment: Opa, boa noite, pode por favor me explicar o que pretende fazer? Você tem um site que você precisa obter somente o que tem dentro de uma div que possui uma classe "x" é isso?

Comment: exatamente amigo, preciso buscar o conteudo de outro site de uma determinada tag, através da ClassName, coloquei esse codigo acima para exemplificar

Comment: Entendi, eu já fiz isto, você irá utilizar cURL, não estou na frente de um computador agora, mais tarde caso não tenha solucionado, me comprimento em colocar um exemplo aqui!

Comment: Editei para evitar erros. veja se funciona dessa forma.

Comment: A DOM é mais completa e mais complicada que, para o seu caso, acaba matando uma formiga com uma bala de canhão. Experimenta com a [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);
    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.agropan.coop.br/cotac.htm");

    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $DOM->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    $finder = new DomXPath($DOM);
    $classname = 'MsoNormal';
    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $result=$result.$node->nodeValue."***";
    }

    $result = preg_replace(array("/\t/", "/\s{2,}/", "/\n/"), array("", " ", " "), $result);
    $partes = explode('***',$result);
    $cotacoes=$partes[0];
    $cotacoes = trim(preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '', $cotacoes));
    $cotacoes = str_replace("COTAÃ‡Ã•ES", "", $cotacoes);

    echo $cotacoes;     

    ?>
```

> Outras formas de se evitar erros devidos a entidades inválidas "Tag o:p invalid in Entity".

1: Fazendo replace dessas entidades inválidas:

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);
    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.agropan.coop.br/cotac.htm");

    $search = array("<o:p>", "</o:p>");
    $replace = array("", "","<div>");
    $html = str_replace($search, $replace, $html);

    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->loadHTML($html);
    $finder = new DomXPath($DOM);
    $classname = 'MsoNormal';
    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $result=$result.$node->nodeValue."***";
    }

    $result = preg_replace(array("/\t/", "/\s{2,}/", "/\n/"), array("", " ", " "), $result);
    $partes = explode('***',$result);
    $cotacoes=$partes[0];
    $cotacoes = trim(preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '', $cotacoes));
    $cotacoes = str_replace("COTAÃ‡Ã•ES", "", $cotacoes);

    echo $cotacoes;     

    ?>
```

2: Usando um @ em $DOM->loadHTML($html); `@$DOM->loadHTML($html);

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);
    $html = file_get_contents("http://www.agropan.coop.br/cotac.htm");

    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    @$DOM->loadHTML($html);
    $finder = new DomXPath($DOM);
    $classname = 'MsoNormal';
    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $result=$result.$node->nodeValue."***";
    }

    $result = preg_replace(array("/\t/", "/\s{2,}/", "/\n/"), array("", " ", " "), $result);
    $partes = explode('***',$result);
    $cotacoes=$partes[0];
    $cotacoes = trim(preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '', $cotacoes));
    $cotacoes = str_replace("COTAÃ‡Ã•ES", "", $cotacoes);

    echo $cotacoes;     

    ?>
```

> Por id basta substituir

```
$classname = 'MsoNormal';
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

por

```
$id = 'MsoNormal';
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@id, '$id')]");
```

Comment: obrigado por ajudar, tentei assim, mas aqui pareceu varios erros, como "Notice: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Namespace prefix o is not defined in Entity, line: 462" e "Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag o:p invalid in Entity" e "Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression"

Comment: Se você olhar o código fonte da página www.agropan.coop.br/cotac.htm vai entender esses erros. Tem tag p class=MsoNormal cujo conteúdo é <o:p></o:p>. Então o erro é que a Tag o: p é uma entidade inválida. Para evitar isso adicionei no código libxml_clear_errors();

Comment: No mais, só pedindo ao dono da página para evitar de usar entidades inválidas.

Comment: sensacional amigo, muito obrigado por sua ajuda, agora vou estudar esse codigo e me aprofundar, grande abraço

Comment: Leo, o que mudaria se ao invés de Class ser por ID?

Comment: @WladerMuriloAlexandro `$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@id, '$classname')]");` Ai pra ficar bonito vc muda `$classname`  para `$id`

Comment: $id = 'MsoNormal'; 
    $nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@id, '$id')]");

Answer (score 0):

No php você precisa fazer algumas alterações no php.ini para ele permitir que o file_get_contents consiga ler urls, file_get_contents tem a finalidade de ler arquivos, e por acaso ele também acessar Urls, por este motivo eu acredito ser melhor o uso do cUrl uma vez que este tem está finalidade e também mais suporte para! Mas sinta-se a vontade para utilizá-lo.

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Obtenha o código do endereço que você quer, e com expressão regular, capture o nó da classe que você precisa, acredito ser o melhor jeito de se fazer isto!

Veja abaixo um exemplo de expressão para isto...

```
^<[a-z]\s[a-z]+\=[MsoNormal]+\salign=center\sstyle=\'text-align\:center\'\>\s+(.*)\s
```

Talvez isto resolva!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss pois bem, no php você precisa fazer algumas alterações no php.ini para ele permitir que o file_get_contents consiga ler urls, file_get_contents tem a finalidade de ler arquivos, e por acaso ele também acessar Urls, por este motivo eu acredito ser melhor o uso do cUrl uma vez que este tem está finalidade e também mais suporte para! Mas sinta-se a vontade para utilizá-lo. 

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss feito!

Comment: Obrigado Marcus, deu certo aqui amigo